# Transistor bins - effect on speed

Tags: transistors

Let's say we have vanilla BC846 (80V), BC847 (50V), BC848 (30V) transistors from the same company, each with 3 bins A, B, C where C supposed to have to highest hfe.

Is that correct, that BC846C should be the fastest, and for example BC847C or BC846B are slower (i.e. have higher capacitances and slower switch-on/off speed)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think they're equally fast, since [the datasheet](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/BC/BC846.pdf) mentions just one value for \$f_T\$, not different values per \$h_{FE}\$ class.

Comment: Yes, that's official information. But in reality they should be different - lower max. voltage and higher hfe should mean thinner base => higher speed.

Comment: @BarsMonster, Or they could be adding dopant which has a small change in leakage current and causing the channel to have a higher mobility. There is no way to just look at two transistors and know based off of voltage rating.

Comment: I an impression, that pins appears from the fact that parameters have some variation, and transistors are just sorted by the results of actual tests...

Comment: @BarsMonster: for \$H_{FE}\$ very likely, for \$V_{CE}\$ I don't know. How would you test this non-destructively?

Comment: Vce brakedown is not destructive when you do so with controlled current (i.e. 1-10ma max).